# Azure Machine Learning Service writing to AzureDataLakeGen2Datastore

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I registered an azure storage account gen2 where datalake filesystem enabled as a datastore as

```
    _ = Datastore.register_azure_data_lake_gen2(workspace='xxx',
                                                datastore_name='store-identifier',
                                                filesystem= 'container',
                                                account_name= 'xxx',
                                                subscription_id= 'xxx',
                                                resource_group= 'xxx',
                                                overwrite=1)
```

I tried uploading files to this using

```
 destination_store = Datastore.get(workspace, 'store-identifier');
 destination_store.upload(
     src='data/', target_path="data_science/", overwrite=True
 )
```

> AzureDataLakeGen2Datastore' object has no attribute 'upload'

When i opened the underlying `AzureDataLakeGen2Datastore` it mentions that the class does not support an upload and asks users to use a `Dataset` instance to upload data. However  I tried both `Dataset.Tabular.upload` and `Dataset.Files.upload` however neither of them support support this functionality

How should i proceed further. Is this functionality not yet supported via azure machine learning ?

Comment: Hi, yes, AzureDataLakeGen2Datastore does not support upload method. Have you tried below way to create and read dataset? Step1, create a dataset follow this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-register-data-assets?tabs=Python-SDK#create-a-uri_folder-data-asset Step 2, read the dataset as this way - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-read-write-data-v2?tabs=Python-SDK#read-v1-data-assets